# Typescript: optional method param based on type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a method where id is only available when it is of type B, look below

```
(index: string, type: ResourceType.A, data: any): JSX.Element;
```

and

```
(index: string, type: ResourceType.B, data: any, id: string): JSX.Element;
```

So I tried to create a method overload as

```
type IOverload = {
  (index: string, type: ResourceType.A, data: any): JSX.Element;
  (index: string, type: ResourceType.B, data: any, id: string): JSX.Element;
}
```

and now tried to create a method as

```
const getJsx: IOverload = (
    index: string,
    type: ResourceType.A | ResourceType.B,
    data: any,
    id?: string
  )=> {
.
.
.
type === ResourceType.B ? myFunc(id) : yourFunc(data)
}
```

and my method `myFunc` is declared as

```
const myFunc = (id: string) => {
```

but now I get an error as shown below for `myFunc`

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Please help to solve this, I would prefer making a change to `getJsx` and
don't want to declare my method `myFunc` with `string | undefined` as

```
const myFunc = (id: string| undefined) => {
```

Comment: It's quite simple. Because your call overload intentionally allows that `id` not be passed, it may be `undefined`. The only way to `myFunc` correctly is to check `id` before calling it. In other words, TS is catching what would likely be a runtime error, exactly as it's designed to do. Without knowing the details of your code, my best guess is this: `ResourceType.B  && id !== undefined ? myFunc(id) : yourFunc(data)`

Comment: this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You could create an overload which will throw an error if a resource is not of `Resource.B` and there are 4 parameters ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA7CgG8BYAKCigEEAaKAITIF8yyAzMENAFwEtEQoXBFwAUPEABNgADwBcUeFxTiA5rS55g8uElQYc+AHR1aEgIZcz8syGy0eE+YuUgVASmu2A3Gw7c+AkKKYpIyTkqq6praCMjoWJqGNFDmlp7YHlA22D6k7Jy8-ILCIoZlZigq8PIizqpQAD6wsXoJ+G4A2gC6bkRkFGj8ilDiUtJQALxZlfAdAAxdWfAKEa79UIMgwxr4k9NVHQCMi2bLOnH6muubw6lmexUHAEwny9nXQ1wjEg8zHQDMrxWLhUjSgHCkrHEwAkTBYpCCogA5GYAEZoJG0c6tAzAJK0JEQbAAEQsZkxUEJ2AAkhIkb0APQMqCYAAWKEQAHdlsAUByUGRESIUeiKdj4rj8ZSiaTLPSKArFUyqGgMLghLDSIKSiKMViWhLEiZpSSyRSqbT5crKKrgOqYdrgrqxQbLkZjVTZeTeoqlcy2RzuVBefygA)):

```
enum ResourceType {
  A, B
}

function test(index: string, type: ResourceType.B, data: any, id: string): any;
function test(index: string, type: ResourceType.A, data: any): any;
function test(...args: (string | ResourceType)[]) {
  const index = args[0] as string
  const type = args[1] as ResourceType
  const data = args[2] as any
  const id = args[3] as string | undefined
}

test('abc', ResourceType.A, 'myData', 'myId') // Throws error
test('abc', ResourceType.A, 'myData')         // Accepted

test('abc', ResourceType.B, 'myData', 'myId') // Accepted
test('abc', ResourceType.B, 'myData')         // Throws error
```

Comment: You created a type, not an overload.

Comment: Indeed. This is great for JavaScript consumers, might not follow the types. You might want to mention the implementation of the overload doesn't contribute to the overload set so TypeScript consumers will get an error if they try to misuse it.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes I created a type with overloads because that is how I can overload an arrow function

Comment: the `type` and the overloaded `function` are just different ways of writing essentially the same types. You can transform each one into the other, so the stylistic difference doesn't invalidate this answer or the form in the question. The overloaded `function` approach is cleaner and easier to read however.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't understand that `id` is never `undefined` in that situation, because the argument is declared as optional with `?`.

I don't know if it's possible to properly type your functions to work as you intend (I don't know how to do it), but a quick fix that would remove your error is to provide a default with nullish coalescing:

```
type === ResourceType.B 
   ? myFunc(id ?? '') // Here typescript is happy, because there is a string fallback if id is undefined
   : yourFunc(data)
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply do

```
myFunc(id as string)
```

And you problem is solved